# plugin crashes after installation - NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, plugins, classpath

I´m testing my plugin here in a separate Eclipse installation. I could create a Feature and install it via update site.

But, when I try to run it, I get a NullPointerException from a line when it calls a code from a JAR file inside my project.

All required JARs are in my lib folder and my plugin compiles fine.
But it appenas that it can´t find them in runtime, so I get NPE.

Here are my files:
 - build.properties:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
           META-INF/,\
           .,\
           icons/,\
           plugin.properties,\
           templates/,\
           lib/,\
           resources/,\
           lib/asas-base.jar,\
           lib/asas-crypt.jar,\
           lib/asas-dbmssql.jar,\
           lib/asas-dboracle.jar,\
           lib/asas-dbtools.jar,\
           lib/asas-dbtoolsmssql.jar,\
           lib/asas-dbtoolsoracle.jar,\
           lib/asas-jdbc.jar,\
           lib/asas-kernel.jar,\
           lib/asas-rts.jar,\
           lib/asas-sbb.jar,\
           lib/asas-ui.jar
```

- MANIFEST.MF file:

  ```
  Bundle-ClassPath: .,
  lib/org.eclipse.e4.xwt_0.9.1.SNAPSHOT.jar,
  lib/org.eclipse.e4.xwt.forms_0.9.1.SNAPSHOT.jar,
  lib/asas-base.jar,
  lib/asas-crypt.jar,
  lib/asas-dbmssql.jar,
  lib/asas-dboracle.jar,
  lib/asas-dbtools.jar,
  lib/asas-dbtoolsmssql.jar,
  lib/asas-dbtoolsoracle.jar,
  lib/asas-jdbc.jar,
  lib/asas-kernel.jar,
  lib/asas-rts.jar,
  lib/asas-sbb.jar,
  lib/asas-ui.jar
  ```

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot.

Here´s the stack-trace I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at br.com.senior.wb.asas.model.utils.AsasUtils.createObject(AsasUtils.java:276)
at br.com.senior.wb.asas.model.utils.AsasComponentManager.createComponent(AsasComponentManager.java:11)
at br.com.senior.wb.asas.gef.part.CreateCommand.innerExecute(AsasComponentCommands.java:42)
at br.com.senior.wb.asas.gef.part.CreateCommand$1.run(AsasComponentCommands.java:36)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.run(ExecutionUtils.java:324)
at br.com.senior.wb.asas.gef.part.CreateCommand.execute(AsasComponentCommands.java:33)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.gef.core.EditDomain.executeCommand(EditDomain.java:59)
at org.eclipse.wb.gef.core.tools.Tool.executeCommand(Tool.java:209)
at org.eclipse.wb.gef.core.tools.AbstractCreationTool.handleButtonUp(AbstractCreationTool.java:62)
at org.eclipse.wb.gef.core.tools.Tool.mouseUp(Tool.java:395)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.gef.core.EditDomain.mouseUp(EditDomain.java:255)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.gef.graphical.EditEventManager.mouseUp(EditEventManager.java:149)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.draw2d.EventManager$8.invoke(EventManager.java:325)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.mouseUp(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:220)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Comment: Have you added all required files to the 'build.properties'? If a file is not listed in that it will not be included in the plugin jar.

Comment: yes...they all are in bin.includes attribute...need anything else?

Comment: also...weird is that all these JARs are inside plugin JAR, when I install it...seems that it can´t execute code from there...

Comment: Jars must also be listed in the 'Bundle-Classpath' in the MANIFEST.MF (Classpath on the Runtime tab of the manifest editor).

Comment: Can you post stack trace for exception?

Comment: they´re all listed in MANIFEST.MF file also...each one of them...

Comment: NPE means you dereferenced null, usually by calling a method on an object that was null. So what was null?

Comment: yes...null is a variable that gets its value from a code that is inside my JAR files...that´s the problem..

Comment: We need to see the stack trace

Comment: I just added the stack-trace...thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem here.
Problem was in how I was getting to plugin.xml file to read some information from there.
Here´s how I fixed it:

```
            InputStream is = FileLocator.openStream(Activator.getDefault().getBundle(), new Path("plugin.xml"), false);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Without this, my plugin doesn´t work correctly.

Thanks for all your help.